# Greater Than > or Plus +

Tags: data, math

I want to convey a requirement that has a minimum but no maximum to my users.
For instance 8.

Which is more understandable?
Participants: >8
or
Participants: 8+
?

*From layouts point of view >8 is more favorable because it can be right aligned along with other numbers too.*

Comment: If you want to get technical, they each have different meanings anyway. **>8** = greater than 8 **8+** = greater than or equal to 8

Comment: It depends on the context.  In the wrong context 'participants 8+' could be read as those who are over 8 years old.

Comment: @nick What about ≥8?

Comment: @Knu technically correct but UTF-8/ect extended characters are generally good to avoid.

Comment: I believe that the "8+" form is very particular to the engilsh language. So take that into account if you're doing something that will be translated into multiple languages.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possibly neither, they each have different meanings:

**>8** = greater than 8
**8+** = greater than or equal to 8

Comment: Uh, ok, so then how about `>7` vs. `8+`?

Comment: **8+** is more intuitive to me at a glance. **>7** would be used in a mathematical context, but in a UI, I would use **8+** myself.

Answer (score 17):

Definitely `8+`.  I've met college graduates who still get the less than and greater than signs mixed up.

Comment: What about +8 ?

Comment: @MoeSweet - I don't think so.  You never really see the `+` before the number with this kind of thing.  If right-aligning is such an issue, couldn't you just pad the numbers that don't have a `+` with a single space?

Comment: I would interpret +8 as a stupid way to write 8 (in contrast to -8).

Comment: If you're dealing with a gamer, +8 means you add 8 to an object or action (I have a cloak with +8 dexterity). 8+ would mean you have to achieve something of at least 8 (you need to roll 8+ in order to kill the dragon). So there's some more...esoteric logic behind the differences.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find enough people who will not understand `8+` (basically everybody who works outside of IT). But everybody who attended a school should understand `>7`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you not write it in English? "More than 8" "8 or greater" "8 or more"?

Comment: Doesn't have space for that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

We had this discussion internally and went for 8+. It seems to make most sense to most people. >8 refers to math while you are more likely to come across 8+ when for example checking the pricing table at Disneyland.

Comment: Agreed.  `<` and `>` are used in programming, mathematics, etc.  But they aren't seen and used in every day life for most people.

Answer (score 0):

@PhillipW made a good point. It depends the context. With 8+ you may have double meaning, while >8 is a safer choice.

Answer (score 0):

**"min. 8" or "8 min.".** This is of course longer than what you have proposed but it is more verbose and has less of a change of being misunderstood.

Comment: Doesn't have space for that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

“**8+**” might be ambiguous as it could be interpreted as “***more than* 8**.”

I’d use “**≥8**.”